# Infinite ascending sequence in Racket

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, infinite-sequence

Is there an analog of Python's [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)  in Racket? I want to create an infinite stream of evenly spaced numbers. [`in-naturals`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-naturals%29%29) is similar to what i want, but does not provide step. I'd want not to reinvent the wheel, but if there's no equivalent function, how to write one? (i presume, generators should be used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the same functionality of Python's [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) using [`in-range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-range%29%29) with an infinite `end` value:

```
(define (count start step)
  (in-range start +inf.0 step))
```

For example:

```
(define s (count 2.5 0.5))

(stream-ref s 0)
=> 2.5
(stream-ref s 1)
=> 3.0
(stream-ref s 2)
=> 3.5
(stream-ref s 3)
=> 4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the function yourself can be done in a single line:

```
(define (stream-from n s) (stream-cons n (stream-from (+ n s) s)))
```

To test it, you here is an example that prints 100000 numbers:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/stream)

(define (stream-from n s) (stream-cons n (stream-from (+ n s) s)))

(define (stream-while s p)
  (let ([fst (stream-first s)])
  (if (p fst) (stream-cons fst (stream-while (stream-rest s) p)) empty-stream)))

(define test (stream-while (stream-from 0 1) (λ (x) (< x 100000))))

(stream-for-each println test)
```